# ExtJs modern 6.0.2: Painted event not triggered in some cases on Chrome 90

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, extjs6-modern

In sencha **Extjs 6.0.2 Modern**, the painted event is not triggered on Ext.dataview.List components for Chrome 90.
Tested on desktop.

[Checkout this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3d2u)

Answer (score 7):

Adding this to my app.scss solved the problem in my case

```
.x-paint-monitor.cssanimation {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.0010ms;
    animation-duration: 0.0010ms;
}
```

The duration of `0.0010ms` was the minimum that worked well.

Comment: Thanks @yannisalexiou, this worked for me  in Sencha touch 2.3 too.

Comment: It doesn't works for me but thanks anyway.